# Addition involving numeric(0) values

Tags: r, numeric, addition

Suppose x is a real number, or a vector. i is valued-False. Then x[i] will return numeric(0). I would like to treat this as a real number 0, or integer 0, which are both fit for addition.

numeric(0) added to any real number will return numeric(0), whereas I wish to obtain the real number being added as the result. What can I do to convert the numeric (0) value? Thanks in advance!

Comment: write a helper function `as_num <- function(x) {if (length(x)==0) 0 else x}` then you could do `as_num(5[FALSE]) + 5`

Comment: The real issue is that `numeric(0)` has no length... which can cause other problems as well. If you give more context we might be able to help you avoid the problem entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only when we do the `+`, it is a problem.  This can be avoided if we use `sum`

```
sum(numeric(0), 5)
#[1] 5
sum(numeric(0), 5, 10)
#[1] 15
```

Or if we need to use `+`, an easy option is to concatenate with `0`, select the first element.  If the element is `numeric(0)`, that gets replaced by 0, for other cases, the first element remain intact

```
c(numeric(0), 0)[1]
#[1] 0
```

Using a small example

```
lst1 <- list(1, 3, numeric(0),  4, numeric(0))
out <- 0
for(i in seq_along(lst1)) {
       out <- out + c(lst1[[i]], 0)[1]
  }

out
#[1] 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max`/`min` with 0 to get 0 as output when input is `numeric(0)`.

```
x <- 1:10
max(x[FALSE], 0)
#[1] 0

min(x[FALSE], 0)
#[1] 0
```